# How to see only the files created in the last 24 hours in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following code. It's working, but the problem is, for example, if now is 8:20PM, the code sees all files after 8:20PM of the previous day. I need after 12AM of the previous day.

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.log |
    Sort CreationTime -Descending |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

How I fix it?

Comment: For clarification: Do you want 12 noon, or 12 midnight? 12PM is noon, but this terminology often causes confusion.

Comment: Your question is unclear, the comparison `-gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` will return files newer than 24hours not until.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong when I was translate for english, is 12AM (midnight). In my country we use 24-hour clock.

Comment: I corrected the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Thursday, 12 September 2019 8:20:00 PM

((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date
Thursday, 12 September 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

Getting the `Date` property of your `DateTime` object will set the time to midnight. If you are after Noon, you could always add 12 hours by doing `((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date.AddHours(12)`

Very messy way about doing it, but it works.

Comment: `(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1)` is probably slightly simpler.

Comment: Thank you! I've tested and it worked of the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I would frame it this way.  EDIT:  changed from 12pm to 12am after the question changed.

```
[datetime]'12:00am' - [timespan]'1'  

Wednesday, September 11, 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

So:

```
get-childitem | where creationtime -gt ([datetime]'12:00am' - [timespan]'1')
```